# ASCII Revision Graph Tool or Extension for Subversion?

Tags: svn, ascii-art, revision-graph

Is there a tool, library, or extension that generates ASCII art-style (like the kind of art cowsay or JavE produce) revision graphs for Subversion repositories, and thus could be used within a command-line interface?

I would like to add the capability to generate a revision graph to a bash script, that I use at work, that currently acts as a kind of simple decision support system for interacting with a repository.

The key functionality that I'm searching for is the ability to render a revision graph in a command-line interface, as opposed to generating an image or vector file that would require leaving the CLI environment.

The closest thing to what I'm searching for appears to be the **[GraphlogExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GraphlogExtension)** of Mercurial. I don't have experience with Mercurial; however, I'd also be interested in any suggestions as to how the GraphlogExtension might be able to be modified for use with SVN.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use [git2svn](http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html) in order to get svn synchroniced as a git repository...

Then using git tools, you could get it (`git log --pretty=format:'%h : %s' --topo-order --graph`). you can read more, an get it more accurate to your needs on [pimping out git log](http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/pimping-out-git-log)

Comment: Thank you, Neo, for the suggestion...I may have to go that route if I want to integrate this functionality.